# What is this text in this locked answer?

Tags: discussion, locked-posts, zalgo

What is all this text in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1732454/2142994)?
Could anyone explain this to me?

[image]

This is the question: [RegEx match open tags except XHTML self-contained tags](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1732348)

My question is not *What is a “locked” post?*, it is **What is the text in this post?** Is it actually the answer?

Also I would like to see the raw text (edit page). Just curious!

**Edit :**

Its from [Zlango text generator](http://www.eeemo.net/). I got that, but why is such unrelated text part that answer?

**So are you saying its OK to type irrelevant text after answering a question?** Just to prove that the question was horrible?

Comment: Right-click, Inspect (Element). Then you can see the HTML. Also, look up Zalgo on the internet. It was a meme a while back.

Comment: Can you really not read that?  I mean it does take a bit more work to read through it, but you should be *able* to if you take your time and look closely.

Comment: I at least thank you for not flagging it. We only have 103 declined flags on that answer.

Comment: @Servy What is that? and why is it like that? We don't usually write like that do we?

Comment: @BradLarson I don't blame the *flaggers*. It makes no sense to have a meme in the answer. The answer is in the first line.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan Cool but why do we have it in an answer?

Comment: A little hard to explain how a meme works. Basically, it was funny at the time, and used as a form of hyperbole.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan I do agree that a hyperbole would have been fun & all of the folks had fun. But since its the answer now, why not edit to make it precise?

Comment: Zalgo in this answer is used to demonstrate how futile are attempts to use regex to parse html

Comment: @gnat I get that but then again why not just why not type down "It a horrible idea to parse XML with RegEx"?

Comment: @AniMenon Because it would detract from the weight of the answer.

Comment: @Sery To put up irrelevant text in an answer is not at all a way to answer a question. How would it be wrong to just say "No it can't be done & it doesn't make sense to do it this way."?

Comment: @AniMenon Because then the answer wouldn't be as strong. The 'irrelevant' text (which is 100% relevant) adds to the convincingness of the answer.

Comment: I find it no where relevant, nor do the 103 close voters! Its ok to put it up for a while, but then at least edit it later to show a simple precise answer.

Comment: @AniMenon You're certainly welcome to that opinion, and if the post weren't locked, you could vote on it to express that opinion.  You could even post your own competing answer that was more concise (as many others did).  What's *not* appropriate is to edit someone else's answer to be in line with how you would rather it be.

Comment: my understanding is, "a horrible idea" answers were given hundreds times prior to Zalgo but lemmings kept asking. Zalgo was a (successful) attempt to make a [meta-tag:canonical] dupe target so that folks could close as duplicate instead of wasting efforts on repeating "horrible idea" again and again and again

Comment: @Servy Thanks for the clarification. But why aren't we editing/deleting it again? I know its funny, emphasizes on the stupidity of the question & all. But its a little irrelevant to have so much irrelevant text in an answer.

Comment: @AniMenon Removing it when it's used for emphasis and to help make a point, and _is_ relevant to the answer as all of that text is _still_ focused on parsing HTML with Regex, would be an edit that _clearly conflicts with the author's intentions._ That is a reason to reject a suggested edit, and a reason to rollback an applied edit. The author used a meme to _make a point,_ but also focused the meme on the topic at hand. It's relevant, it's emphasis on the point of the answer, therefore it is relevant.

Comment: @AniMenon You think it's irrelevant.  *Many* more disagree with you.  We don't edit it because your one opinion doesn't get to overrule everyone else's (including, relevantly, the author's).  It's their post, and they can express their views how they want (within the rules of this site, which this does).  The fact that you would have answered the question differently doesn't mean you get to edit other people's answers to match what you want, it means you can write your own answer.

Comment: @gnat We have so many duplicates. Do you think putting up such text helps?

Comment: @AniMenon We have lots of evidence to indicate that it does, so...yes.

Comment: @Servy Its not my one opinion, Its all those "flaggers", "down-votes" & ppl still wanting to get it removed because its not a precise answer to the question. Well anyway, if you all feel it should be there, good lets have a funny answer :)

Comment: if you were (like that answer author) one of the folks who had to repeat hundreds times "horrible idea" before Zalgo came up you probably wouldn't ask

Comment: @gnat It in no ways helps reduce duplicates, it in fact increases them since people are not clear whats going on in that answer. Well anyway, lets keep the funny answer :)

Comment: @AniMenon No, it's not just your one opinion, but it is the opinion of a very small minority.  The *overwhelming majority* of readers have found the answer to be very helpful, so the net effect of the answer existing (as it is) has made it extremely helpful.

Comment: it's not about reducing duplicate _questions_ (lemmings will keep asking no matter what) but about reducing effort to repeat answers to these questions

Comment: @AniMenon There are going to be lots of duplicates of this question no matter what you do, because the people who are going to post those duplicates are the people not doing searches before asking their question.  All we can really do is make it as easy as possible to close those questions as soon as they're asked.

Comment: @gnat this question came up when I just saw a duplicate question.

Comment: [It is an official meme](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19478/the-many-memes-of-meta/216029#216029) (cross-site).

Comment: @AniMenon So?  How is that inconsistent with Gnat's point?

Comment: @Sery Not inconsistent, hence ending discussion. Funny post wins :D

Comment: @PeterMortensen I didn't know of that. Thanks.

Comment: This wasn't just another "funny post". bobince answered this question so many times in the proper fashion that he finally broke and wrote this twisted but timeless response. It is not a guideline for future answering, just a part of Stack Overflow history at this point. Do not use the bobince post to make any inference about future posting.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Zalgo text.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6579844/how-does-zalgo-text-work) Here's the edit page, although it's not exactly interesting...

[image]

Comment: Ok. Its good its in *Zlango* text, why is it part of the answer? That part of the answer has nothing to do with the question!

Comment: @AniMenon It's in the answer because the answerer typed it into the box. It does serve to illustrate the unhappiness and chaos that occurs when someone parses HTML with Regexes.

Comment: @AniMenon parsing xml with regex brings on the apocalypse.

Comment: @Will & @ Undo I get it. Its a horrible idea to parse XML with regex but that text has nothing to do with the answer!

Comment: @AniMenon It's called artistic license. The answerer decided to type his answer in this way. It's relevant, so we're not going to remove it.

Comment: @Undo Also there are 103 close flags, why do you think people have put it? Don't you think that answer would look weird if someone just searches for "RegEx for XML parse"?

Comment: @AniMenon There were 103 flags, not close flags.  Big difference.  And most of them seemed to think it was just a bug, and didn't realize it was intentional.  And then of course there are the thousands of users that found the post helpful.  Also note that there are likely some number of users that cast multiple flags, so that's not necessarily 103 users who had a problem with it.

Comment: @Servy yes 103 flags, delete or bug or irrelevant etc. Anyway lets just keep the funny answer since you all like it so much :D

Comment: @AniMenon So you're saying that the tens of thousands (if not hundreds of thousands) of people who have been made better off for having seen the answer shouldn't have had that opportunity because 100 people were confused by it?

Comment: I am certain many new users would have never got the meme & not bothered voting/flagging it even if it were locked. Also I didn't know it was part of **[Memes of Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/19478/325200)**

Comment: @AniMenon The fact that they wouldn't have gotten the joke wouldn't make the answer not answer their question, it's just make it a bit less entertaining.

Comment: @Sery cool man I got your point. I was just looking at a different aspect (when I asked the question).

Comment: It's like explaining humor to an alien

Comment: OK, now we want to know what is the orange box ...

Comment: @rene Userscript to move some useful bits around. That orange box just shows how many flags have been cast on the post.